# GDI+, large translation values, and distorted rendering of graphic primitives

Tags: gdi+

Long-time user of S.O., but first-time poster. Please be gentle. :)

Using .NET's GDI+ (any version of the Framework, from 2,0 on up to 4.5.1), I get very strange behaviour when rendering graphics primitives with large translation values on the 'Graphics' object. Here is a very simple piece of code that demonstrates the issue...simply paste in into a windows form and run:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(183946953, 82803840)

    Dim r As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(-183946600.0, -82803570.0), New Size(0, 0))
    r.Inflate(25, 25)

    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, r)
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, r)
End Sub
```

The resulting ellipse is badly distorted. And the higher the translation values, the worse the distortion gets.

Does anyone know why GDI+ does this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally GDI+ uses a fixed point coordinate representation for some operations. You may be running into a 24 bit limit for the integer portion of the coordinates. The work around is to avoid the translation: no one can see anything drawn at those coordinates. If you are doing the translation in order to render to a printer or bitmap, you will need to scale down all your coordinates.